# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException Error while reading Binary String

Tags: java, string, exception

I have a long String with binary values. And i have a hash map that has the Binary digits as a key and char as a value. I have a function that supposed to read the binary string using 2 pointers and compare with hashmap and store the corresponding char in main.decodedTxt. However, im getting string out of bound exception for this. I don't know how to solve this. I'm getting exception on "String temp =" line. I have a picture link of the console output to see better picture.

```
 public static void bitStringToText (String binText){
    String bs = binText;
    int from =0;
    int to = 1;

    while(bs != null){
        String temp = bs.substring(from, to);
        if (main.newMapDecoding.containsKey(temp)){
        main.decodedTxt += main.newMapDecoding.get(temp);
        from =to;
        to = from +1;
        } else {
            to = to + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

[Image of console exception is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yne0l.png)

Comment: Would you please post the complete code so that we can have a better understanding of the workflow of the complete program?

Comment: Have you tried to debug or simply printing the `binText` parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all there is no need to check if `bs` is `null` because no part of your code changes the value of `bs`. Your current code will cross the possible index of your `binText` at some point. It's better to loop just `binText` and check if you find something within it. After all you have to traverse the complete string anyways. Change your code as follows

```
public static void bitStringToText (String binText){

//no need to do this if you are not modifying the contents of binText
//String bs = binText; 

int from =0;
int to = 1;
int size = binText.length();
String temp = "";

while(to <= size ){
    temp = binText.substring(from, to);
    if (main.newMapDecoding.containsKey(temp)){
    main.decodedTxt += main.newMapDecoding.get(temp);
    from =to;
    to = from +1;
    } else {
        to = to + 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

First, give it a try to practice debugging. It is an easy case. Either use run in debug mode (place break point on `String temp = bs.substring(from, to);` line) or print values of `from` and `to` before the same line. It will help to understand what is going on.

---

**Solution:**

If `bs` is not null you will always have StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. Because you are not checking if `to` is pointing to not existed index of `bs` String. Easiest example of the first one will be empty String: `bs == ""`.

One of the solution could be to replace condition in while to `while (to <= bs.length())`.